# Uploading .csv file using arules

Tags: r, arules

I am trying to upload a `.csv` file using `arules` library but the data is not uploaded in table format but upon using `View()`, it is showing some clickable tabs, with columns namely: Name, Type, Value  without actual data.

Can you please tell me how I can bring it in table format? Thanks!

```
groc <- read.transactions(file.choose())
```

Comment: Hi, maybe this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972270/how-to-convert-object-of-transaction-to-dataframe-in-r ? This will show you how to convert a transaction object into a data frame

Comment: Without seeing any data or output, or having access to the file you're opening with `file.choose`, it's hard to do more than guess. See [mcve]